# How to display query in output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sparql, rdf, dotnetrdf

So I have a query and am trying to display it in the Debug Output, when I run the file it gives me a list of output starting with iisexpress.exe : https://gyazo.com/fd9eb832dfcc08571b31490103b85b49
but no actual result? I am trying to run a query on Visual Studios2015 for the first time using the dotnetRDF. My code is below:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SQLAQL query example");
            //Define a remote endpoint
            //Use the DBPedia SPARQL endpoint with the default Graph set to DBPedia
            SparqlRemoteEndpoint endpoint = new SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri("http://dbpedia.org/sparql"), "http://dbpedia.org");

            //SPARQL query to show countries, population, capital for countries where population is more than 100000 and limit results to 50
            String queryString = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>  " +
              "PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/> " +
              "PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>  " +
              "SELECT ?country_name ?population ?cptl  " +
              "WHERE {  " +
              "?country rdf:type type:Country108544813.  " +
              "?country rdfs:label ?country_name.  " +
              "?country prop:populationEstimate ?population.  " +
              "?country dbo:capital ?cptl  " +
              "FILTER (?population > 1000000000) .  " +
              "}" +
              "LIMIT 50 ";
            Debug.WriteLine("queryString: [" + queryString + "]");

            //Make a SELECT query against the Endpoint
            SparqlResultSet results = endpoint.QueryWithResultSet(queryString);
            foreach (SparqlResult result in results)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            }

        }
```

Just learning SPARQL so this maybe a very basic question. 
Many Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your code is compiled and run in Debug mode. If is not then `Debug.WriteLine()` will have no effect. The output you have provided is incomplete, future reference it is better to copy and paste into your question rather than posting a screenshot.

Since this appears to be a console application why not just use `Console.WriteLine()` instead?